# how to create general method for all type of class(object)

Tags: java, android, oop

I am using db4o lib for storing data.

for example I have this code for storing data (i.e News)

```
public static void insertNewsToDB(Context context, final News news){
        final String dbPath = context.getDir("news", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/"  + DB4O_NAME;
        ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), dbPath);
        try {
            db.store(news);
            db.commit();
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

and this getting data from db:

```
public static List<News> getNewsListFromDB(Context context){
        final List<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();
        final String dbPath = context.getDir("news", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/"  + DB4O_NAME;
        ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), dbPath);
        try {
            ObjectSet<News> result = db.queryByExample(News.class);
            news.addAll(result);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }

        return news;
    }
```

How could I create method so it's not depend on what type of class I have to pass. More clearly it doesn't depend on second parameter is News,User or something else. And same when I want get news from db.

I need to create general method which is not depend on type of class.

EDIT: I did this but I doesn't work. More clearly trying get list it returns nothing. And I don't get it why
what I did wrong

```
 public static void insertToDB(Context context, final Object obj,final String _key) {
        final String dbPath = context.getDir(_key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/" + DB4O_NAME;
        ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), dbPath);
        try {
            db.store(obj);
            db.commit();
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }
    public static <T> void insertToDB(Context context, final List<T> newsList,String _key) {
        for (T news : newsList) {
            insertToDB(context, news,_key);
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<T> getListFromDB(Context context, final java.lang.Class<T> tClass,final String _key) {
        final List<T> news = new ArrayList<T>();
        final String dbPath = context.getDir(_key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/" + DB4O_NAME;
        ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration(), dbPath);
        try {
            ObjectSet<T> result = db.queryByExample(tClass);
            news.addAll(result);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return news;
    }
```

Comment: "I did this but I doesn't work what I did wrong" what exactly is the question here?

Comment: What happened when you try that? Never just stop at "it doesn't work" while asking question. It isn't a complete question at all. Tell us what was the issue.

Comment: when I try to getList from Db it returning nothing. And I don't understood what wrong here insert or getList

Comment: @pmb Did you check in DB whether data is inserted or not?

Answer (score 0):

use Object as a method parameter type
Or you can user Generics (? or T) based on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you need no type information at all, you could simple switch `News` to `Object`. If you need type information (i.e., persisted objects stick to a certain interface), introduce a generic type parameter.

```
public static <T extends SomeClass> void insertEntityToDB(Context context, final T entity) {
    // ...
}

public static <T extends SomeClass> List<T> getEntityListFromDB(Context context) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Smutje for your answer, I just edited my answer could you look and tell me what wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the concept of Generics in your method calls.

public static void insertNewsToDB(Context context, final News news)

will change to

```
public static void insertNewsToDB(Context context, final <T> T)
```

And

```
public static List<News> getNewsListFromDB(Context context)
```

will change to

```
public static List<T> getNewsListFromDB(Context context)
```